# Keyboard Hide and Appear method Call Multiple Time and on Another View

Tags: objective-c, iphone

My keyboard will hidden and shown method call when we are on another View.
It is my first View.

on view will appear

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardWasShown:) name: UIKeyboardWillShowNotification object:nil];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardWillBeHidden:) name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification object:nil];
```

on view will disappear

```
-(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:UIKeyboardDidShowNotification object:nil];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:UIKeyboardDidHideNotification object:nil];
}
```

On second view their is textfield on editing 
they call my keyboard hidden code . It is not I wanted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to remove Observer for `UIKeyboardWillShowNotification` and `UIKeyboardWillHideNotification` not  `UIKeyboardDidShowNotification` and `UIKeyboardDidHideNotification` ..this may fix your problem